# Traffic limitations on Google Cloud Free Tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running a Compute Engine VM instance and its monthly traffic seems to be large.

- Is there any monthly or free tier period traffic limitations?
- Where    can I get exhaustive information about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google Cloud Platform Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) consists of a 12-month free trial with $300 credit and [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits) usage services. There is no additional limitation or a real difference between the resources that you can use before or after the Free Tier.

Regarding Compute Engine resources you have this Always Free resources:

> 1 non-preemptible f1-micro VM instance per month in one of the
> following US regions:
>
> - Oregon: us-west1
> - Iowa: us-central1 South
> - Carolina: us-east1
>
> 30 GB-months HDD
> 5 GB-month snapshot storage in the following regions:
>
> - Oregon: us-west1
> - Iowa: us-central1 South
> - Carolina: us-east1
> - Taiwan: asia-east1
> - Belgium: europe-west1
>
> 1 GB network egress from North America to all region destinations (excluding China and
> Australia) per month

There is no charge for ingress traffic or egress traffic to the same zone

You can find more information about the networking pricing of Compute Engine [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#network_pricing)

Comment: Please what is meant by "30 GB-months"? Does that mean usage of not more than 30 GB of disk space within one month?

Comment: 30 GB/month means you can provision up to 30 GB of standard disk for free, which translates on the maximum size of the disk that you can select during the configuration of the instance. If you have doubts on if your instance will be eligible for always-free usage you can play with the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=f4a4adb6-4b5e-47bb-a303-39ea41945328) and select the "Include Always Free usage in my estimate" box

Comment: Does that mean that if Google simply described it as "30 GB HDD" instead of "30 GB-months HDD", it will not convey the same intended information? (I mean why the needless confusion if "30 GB-months HDD" is simply 30 GB free disk space?)

Comment: Free tier is time based not resource based. It means you can use two 30GB disks for 15 days or one 30GB disk for 30 days. This is why the usage is quoted in GB-Month.